# unable to update sails 1.0.1 from 0.12.13

Tags: node.js, npm, sails.js

Trying to update sails framework from 0.12.13 to 1.0.1 
I don't know where I am doing wrong.

[image: Unable to upgrade sails 1.0.1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to global node_module directory and try update or install sails

*to find node_module path type npm command in terminal and in last line of the output*

*for mac linux path look like*

> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/